Radial Lebesgue space definition
I understand that one way to define the radial Lebesgue space $L_{rad}^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is by the completation of the space of radial smooth function with compact support, i.e, $L_{rad}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)=\overline{C_{rad,0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\left\|\cdot\right\|_{p}}$ but,   it can also be defined as $L_{rad}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon u\text{ radial function }\right\}$.
Question. Do these two definitions coincide?
Thanks.
